# Return string array of grades

Tags: java, arrays

this is the code

```
public static String[] getgrades(int[] testMarks){
        String grade[] = new String[1000];
        int marks = testMarks[0]; 
        for (int count=0; count < testMarks.length ; count++){
            if (testMarks[count]>90)
                grade[count]="A";
            else if (testMarks[count]>75)
                grade[count]="B";
            else if (testMarks[count]>60)
                grade[count]="C";
            else if (testMarks[count]>40)
                grade[count]="D";
            else
                grade[count]="F";
            return grade[];


        }

    }
```

Comment: This wont compile. And what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

You return the result inside of your loop. That means you never get to the second `grade`.

Place the return statement outside (after) your loop.

Also your `grade[]` has a constant size of 1000 instead of the size you want (which is `testMarks.length`).